# Getting cannot find file exception in Play Framework

Tags: file, scala, playframework-2.2, filenotfoundexception

I have a file called `product.csv` in my application root. I want to read from the file. But I am getting file not found exception. Here is the code I have written.

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile("/product.csv").mkString
println(lines)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using Windows OS.

Comment: Try just .fromFile("product.csv")

Comment: you mean just remove "/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a relative filepath `"product.csv"` rather than `"/product.csv"` which will look at the root of your drive.